# Installing an electric toe kick heater "old work"-style

Tags: electrical, wiring, baseboard

I'd like to install a toe kick heater under the 48"-wide vanity (in the center) seen in the picture. The electrical wire is in the side wall. Do I run the risk that when I cut the toe kick baseboard open, I will find sufficient structural obstructions that I won't be able to get to the wall?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you install a junction box in the wall, and hardwire the appropriate gauge wire through the cabinet bottom, to your heater.

The cabinet is made of wood, you can drill through obstacles to thread your wires.

You need to leave enough slack so you can easily pull the heater for maintenance and cleaning. I recommend a metal flex pigtail with individual wires. On a GFCI circuit.

Which amperage is your heater? Internal thermostat or wall mounted switch/thermostat?

Comment: What if there's a two foot gap between the obstacle and the wall?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "obstacle"? Support for the cabinet? Inaccessible space? I had assumed you could remove the cabinet bottom to wire your heater.

Comment: Like a 2x4 that's part of the base.

Comment: There may be some structure but @albator guidance is the path I would take, you won't know what's under there until you open it up. Most cabinets usually have a perimeter and possibly a cross brace.

Comment: There's a possibility that the entire front board which covers the toe area of the cabinet may be removable. Then you could see everything under there. Even if you have to ding it up a little to get it off, its hardly going to be seen.